# more the one external config file in project

Tags: c#

hello to all
 well i am adding three dll with there config file app1.config,app2.config,app3.config in my windows project. my windows project is having its own app.config file

if i look onto the "file" attribute of appsettings i can specify only one external config.
i dont want to use

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("external.config");

KeyValueConfigurationElement element = config.AppSettings.Settings["key"];
```

how can i solve this problem...

Comment: Why does each DLL have its own app.config?  An application should have an app.config, a DLL generally doesn't.

Comment: i have multiple class lib,with there config,thats y i am having the multiple dll with there config,

Comment: @slash shogdhe, just click on the greyed out check mark beside the answer which you want to accept.

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

- Put all your configuration into one configuration file
- Load them with ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the dll's are reference to a project, the **best way** would be **merge the config settings** for the three config files of the dlls to the projects app.config file.

Comment: sorry,but i dont think this best way to do

Comment: Can you post what are the config elements that are being used by the dll's? If it is something like Nhibernate, log4j, then you can define the config in external config files and load it using the OpenMappedExeConfiguration, but if the config settings are like appSettings then having them in a single file would be better.

Comment: Do you have to merge them by hand or is there an automatic way?